# How to view files generated by webpack in DevTools

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to inspect files generated by webpack from DevTools panel?
They all come empty.

I'm talking about a production application for which I don't have the source code and assets are hosted through CDN.

I can clearly see the tree but not content. Not sure if this is possible? (or at least see the un-minified version)

[image: webpack tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A listing of all the files without being able to see their content is a result of the Webpack devtool option `nosources-source-map`. From their [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/):

> `nosources-source-map` - A SourceMap is created without the
>   sourcesContent in it. It can be used to map stack traces on the client
>   without exposing all of the source code. You can deploy the Source Map
>   file to the webserver.
>
> *It still exposes filenames and structure for decompiling, but it
>   doesn't expose the original code.*

Because the source map is generated without mapping back to the original source material, you won't be able to see the original source code.

---

**EDIT** *When I first read your question, I skipped past the part where you said that this was on an external production application and thought that you were looking to debug your own webpack config by seeing the config itself in the Sources panel. Here's my original answer, in case anyone finds this on Google with that in mind:*

The Sources tab will only show the files loaded into the browser; furthermore, it looks like your average Webpack config hooks into the file system, causing your app to not work out too well if you try importing webpack into it for debug purposes:

[image: what happened when I tried to import my webpack config into my client app]

That being said, you can open Node on your computer and access the webpack config from there:

[image: inspecting webpack config via node on command line]